# logstash: File input not working, stdout does not show anything at all (Windows)

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am new to logstash, I was trying to give a sample log file as input through the logstash config file. But it does not seem to be working. Initially I gave input through stdin, it worked perfectly and showed the output in stdout. I placed the same input I gave through stdin in the log file and tried giving the input but it does not seem to read the file at all. 
This is my config file:

`

```
input { 
    file{
    path =>"C:\pdata\ct.log"
    start_position =>"beginning"
}

}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
  }
}
output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}  
}
```

The presence of sincedb_path does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slashes in your input configuration.

```
input { 
    file{
    path =>"C:/pdata/ctop.log"
    start_position =>"beginning"
}
```